# Create file from shell script (E.g, this-is-the-title)

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a file using the following script (see below). While the script runs without errors (at least according to [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net)), I cannot get the resulting file to have the correct name.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set some variables

export site_path=~/Documents/Blog
drafts_path=~/Documents/Blog/_drafts
title="$title"

# Create the filename

title=$("$title" | "awk {print tolower($0)}")
filename="$title.markdown"
file_path="$drafts_path/$filename"
echo "File path: $file_path"

# Create the file, Add metadata fields

cat >"$file_path" <<EOL
---
title: \"$title\"
layout: 
tags: 
---
EOL

# Open the file in BBEdit

bbedit "$file_path"

exit 0
```

Very new to bash, so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What's the name you expect? What's the (actual) name that you get? Also, as per the Help Center (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you should include only the bare minimum information to reproduce an error in your question -- meaning there's no need for the `bbedit`, no need for the `cat` (unless the "File path:" is correct without it), etc.

Comment: Also, running your title as a command is *obviously* wrong, which is what `title=$("$title" | "awk {print tolower($0)}")` does.

Comment: ...and if you're targeting bash 4, then there's a native syntax for lower-casing strings: `title=${title,,}`

Comment: ...also, `title="$title"` does literally nothing. How are we supposed to know what you want that command to mean/do?

Comment: Also, use `bash -x yourscript` to get a log of commands run over the course of its execution on stderr. Looking carefully at that will let you narrow down where things *start* to go wrong.

Comment: My format for posts uses "yyyy-mm-dd-title", but drafts don't get assigned a date under typical [usage](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/drafts/). It is recommended that dates get add after being moved to the `_posts` directory. Previously, I would get output from the script, but it was blank (e.g, ".markdown").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most glaring error is this:

```
title=$("$title" | "awk {print tolower($0)}")
```

It's wrong for several reasons:

- This pipeline runs `"$title"` as a command -- meaning that it looks for a command named with the title of your blog post to run -- and pipes the output of that command (a command that presumably won't exist) to `awk`.
- Using double-quotes around the entire awk command means you're looking for a command named something like `/usr/bin/awk {print tolower(bash-)}` (if `$0` evaluates to `bash-`, which it will in an interactive interpreter; behavior will differ elsewhere).
- Using double-quotes rather than single-quotes to protect your awk script means that the `$0` gets evaluated to the shell rather than by awk.

---

A better alternative might look like:

```
title=$(awk '{print tolower($0)}' <<<"$title")
```

...or, to use simpler tools:

```
title=$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<"$title")
```

...or, to use bash 4.x built-in functionality:

```
title=${title,,}
```

---

Of course, all that assumes that `title` is set to start with. If you aren't passing it through your environment, you might want something like `title=$1` rather than `title="$title"` earlier in your script.

Comment: Fixing this line does the trick, thanks. In an earlier version, I did have `title-$1` so that I could use `./draft.sh "title"`...not sure why I removed it.